# Keyboard emulation in Wayland

Tags: fedora, wayland, xdotool, xte

Is there a way to make `xdotool` or `xte` or any other alternative to work in Fedora 26?
I'm trying to emulate keypresses (using xbindkeys), e.g. pressing `Alt+B` would emulate pressing `Ctrl+Shift+B`. But apparently neither `xdotool` nor `xte` work in Wayland (for security reasons [?])

Is there a workaround? Otherwise how do I rebind keys to other keys?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1032270/wayland-alternative-for-xorgs-xdotool and https://askubuntu.com/questions/956640/equivalent-to-xdotool-for-wayland

Answer (score 12):

EDIT Feb 2021/Mar 2024: Finally I found a project doing it right: https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper

I'm using this little script. It needs the package evemu installed and sudo-confguration for evemu-event without password-notification. `EVDEVICE` is the device used to emulate the input. `/dev/input/event8` is my keyboard (use `sudo evemu-record` to find yours)

```
#!/bin/bash
# keycomb.sh

EVDEVICE=/dev/input/event8

for key in $@; do
    sudo evemu-event $EVDEVICE --type EV_KEY --code KEY_$key --value 1 --sync
done


# reverse order
for (( idx=${#@}; idx>0; idx-- )); do
    sudo evemu-event $EVDEVICE --type EV_KEY --code KEY_${!idx} --value 0 --sync
done
```

you can e.g. change a tab with `./keycomb.sh RIGHTCTL PAGEDOWN`.

Please note: This script does no validation on parameters, use with care ;)

Comment: Finally got the nice project working on Fedora/Wayland/GNOME after probably `xte` was not helping with `xbindkeys` or isolated, and maybe a small attempt with `evemu-event`.  After `pip` and about 4 `systemtl` commands, I also needed this command after some GUI configuration: `sudo key-mapper-control --command start --device "<keyboard>" --preset "<preset>"`

Comment: Indeed https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper (new project name) is the solution! I would happily vote your answer if only the "EDIT Feb 2021" was featured a bit more prominently - or even better, was a separate answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is too long for a comment, but not really an answer...
I recently came across some [python](https://gist.github.com/meeuw/0271963355ce6667d87fc0b3fbafa45a) code which says

> Simple script to replace xdotool when using Gnome/Wayland for entering keystrokes using evdev.

which could be a starting point.  I have not tried it. It needs the python package [evdev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/evdev), and has to run as user root.

There is also an [evemu](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/) package which says

> evemu records and replays device descriptions and events, making it possible to emulate input devices through the kernel's input system. Emulated devices are for most practical purposes indistinguishable from real devices.